# Compound Poisson Process: Integration into Modified Bessel Functions?

Tags: integration, physics, random-walk, bessel-functions

Consider a continuous time random walk which steps by an exponentially random length $l$ at time-points dictated by a Poisson process of rate $\omega$:

$$ x(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{N(t)} l_k.$$

The number of steps $N(t)$ is distributed as $[(\omega t)^n/n!]e^{-\omega t}$.
The Master equation for the probability of being at position $x$ by time $t$ is

$$ \partial_t p(x,t) = -\omega p(x,t) + \omega \int_0^\infty dl p(x-l,t)h(l),$$
where $h(l)=\lambda e^{-\lambda l}$ is the step length distribution.
How can I find this $p(x,t)$? I expect it's proportional to the modified Bessel function of the first kind $I_1(2\sqrt{\lambda x\omega t})$ from several papers, but these do not explain the derivation. A more general case is described in Cox and Miller (1965) (eq. 157), but they do not evaluate a closed form for $p(x,t)$.

So far, I have tried Fourier transform methods without much success. 
Fourier transforming both sides gives

$$\partial_t \phi(s,t) = -\omega \phi(s,t) + \omega \phi(s,t)\hat{h}(s),$$
where $\hat{h}(s) = \lambda/(\lambda-is)$ is the FT of $h(l)$ and $\phi(s,t)$ is the characteristic function of $p(x,t)$.

Solving this and taking the inverse transform (using initial conditions $p(x,0)=\delta(x)$ or $\phi(s,0)=1$) gives

$$ p(x,t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^\infty ds \exp\Big\{-isx + \frac{i \omega ts}{\lambda - i s} \Big\}, $$
which I can't get much traction on.

Any suggestion to proceed? I tried substitutions to arrive at an integral representation of a bessel function, but no progress yet. I can arrive at forms in integral tables but without the proper limits. Any approaches are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to solve the IVP? If so then some initial data is required.

Comment: $p(x,0)=\delta(x)$ or $\phi(s,0)=1$! Thanks.

Comment: OK, then $p(x,t)=0$ for all $x<0$ and all $t$, so the evolution equation really looks like $\partial_t p = -\omega p + \omega \int_0^x p(x-l,t) h(l) dl$, which is amenable to a spatial Laplace transform (since the convolution is causal). Looks to me like you have $\partial_t \phi(u,t) = \omega \phi(u,t) \left ( -1 + \frac{\lambda}{u+\lambda} \right )$ which you can easily integrate.

Comment: Yes, the characteristic function is easy, but what about $p(x,t)$? I already did this step (except with fourier) to get to the final equation above, I just skipped writing it

Comment: If I have it right, $\phi(u,t)=C(u)e^{-\omega t}+\frac{\lambda}{\omega} \frac{1}{u+\lambda}$. Now $\phi(u,0) \equiv 1$ so $C(u)=1-\frac{\lambda}{\omega} \frac{1}{u+\lambda}$ and $\phi(u,t)=e^{-\omega t} + \frac{\lambda}{\omega} \frac{1}{u+\lambda} \left ( 1-e^{-\omega t} \right )$. But I feel like I made a mistake somewhere, because this is just a weighted average of a point mass and an exponential distribution.

Comment: I think it's easier than that. The ODE is separable so it's $\langle e^{-u x}\rangle = \phi(u,t) = \exp\{-\omega t u/(\lambda + u)\}$, but I'm not sure it provides a cleaner path to $p(x,t)$

Comment: I spotted my mistake, which was losing the multiplication and winding up with a linear inhomogeneous equation by mistake.

Comment: In principle you can expand in powers of $t$ and invert term-by-term. Not sure what else you can do short of simply identifying the answer.

Comment: Identifying the answer is the key ... For someone else in the future: the Laplace transform $\phi(u,t)$ inverts with Prudnikov et al. (Integral and Series, Vol. 5, 1992) 1.1.1.2 followed by 2.2.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this problem than the one discussed earlier in the comments is to marginalize over $N(t)$, meaning that you write

$$p(x,t)=f_{X(t)}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_{X(t)}(x \mid N(t)=n) P(N(t)=n).$$

The reason this method is good is that $f_{X(t)}(x \mid N(t)=n)=\lambda^n \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{-\lambda x}$ and $P(N(t)=n)=e^{-\omega t} \frac{(\omega t)^n}{n!}$ are both known functions. Here we must understand $\frac{x^{-1}}{(-1)!} e^{-\lambda x}$ as $\delta(x)$; this makes sense because the resulting term represents the probability that no jumps happen, i.e. the particle stays at $x=0$ all the way until time $t$.

Plugging that in gives

$$p(x,t)=e^{-\omega t} \delta(x) + e^{-\omega t} e^{-\lambda x} \lambda \omega t \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\lambda x \omega t)^n \frac{1}{n!} \frac{1}{(n+1)!}.$$

As you mentioned in the OP you can now write this in a way like you expected, because $I_1(2\sqrt{\lambda x \omega t})=\sqrt{\lambda x \omega t} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda x \omega t)^n}{n!(n+1)!}$ from https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25#E2 Therefore

$$p(x,t)=e^{-\omega t} \delta(x) + e^{-\omega t} e^{-\lambda x} \sqrt{\frac{\lambda \omega t}{x}} I_1 \left ( 2 \sqrt{\lambda x \omega t} \right ).$$

Comment: Thanks @Ian, this is helpful and useful to see, but this solution is already known to me from the Einstein 1937 PhD thesis (Albert Einstein's son Hans, the river scientist).  I am interested in the solution from a dynamical systems perspective (Fokker-Planck-Kolmogorov approach) since I want to generalize it from this framework. I solved it from this framework with Laplace transform method the other day.

Comment: I realized I have a question about your approach. How can you marginalize over the probability of $n$ steps happening with $n$ rests only? Why is it not possible (in each term of the sum $\sum_n f(x|n)p(t|n)$) to take $n$ steps and $n+1$ rests, where the final rest is still in progress at time $t$? I hope this makes sense -- it's a point of confusion for me.

Comment: Maybe rephrasing is helpful. How do you know that $x,t$ is the termination of a step-rest sequence, rather than being at the termination of a step and a partial rest? I realize for an exponentially distributed resting time these are probably equivalent, but I'm trying to learn how this works with a more general renewal process.

Comment: @kevinkayaks Actually, with probability 1 you are strictly between two jumps at any deterministic time $t$. But that isn't a problem because you are marginalizing over $N(t)$ which is the number of jumps that happened at times $s \leq t$. In particular, the process is cadlag; requiring a process to be cadlag is the standard way to avoid the kind of technicalities that I think are worrying you in the more general situation.

Comment: Thanks Ian, this is helpful